# getting Memory fault while running a perl script

Tags: perl

I have very little understanding on the perl script used here. It was done by a old developer.

i have a script "deploykit.pl"

it internally calls "OracleSqlHelper.pm"

```
use strict;
no warnings 'misc';

package OracleSqlHelper;

use DBI;
BEGIN {
 eval 'use DBD::Oracle qw(:ora_types)' or print "Oracle DBD not installed\n";
}

my $log;
my $env;

sub new
{
   my $class = shift;
   my $self = {};

   bless $self;

   $self->{classname} = ref( $self );
   $self->{connectstring} = ref( $self );
   $self->{schema} = "";
   $self->{password} = "";
   $self->{tnsname} = "";
   $self->{db_handle} = "";

   return bless $self, $class;

}

# -------------------------------------
# Set Log
# -------------------------------------
sub set_log
{
   my $self = shift;
   $log = shift;
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# set_env
# Set the env variable to point to the configuration file parameters
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
sub set_env
{
   my $self = shift;
   $env = shift;
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# set_schema
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
sub set_schema
{
   my $self = shift;
   $self->{schema} = shift;
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# set_password
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
sub set_password
{
   my $self = shift;
   my $pwd  = shift;

   my $temppwd = "\"" . $pwd . "\"";

   $self->{password} = $temppwd;
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# set_tnsname
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
sub set_tnsname
{
   my $self = shift;
   $self->{tnsname} = shift;
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# Disconnect from the database
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
sub db_disconnect
{
   my $self = shift;

   my $method = "db_disconnect";
   $log->log( "*** Enter $method in OracleSqlHelper ***" );

   $self->{db_handle}->disconnect;
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# check_install
# Determine if the Oracle libraries are installed
# Return 0 (false) if the modules are NOT installed
# If the modules aren't then this module should not be used.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
sub check_install
{
   my $self   = shift;
   my $retval = 0;

   my $method = "check_install";
   $log->log( "*** Enter $method in OracleSqlHelper ***" );

   my $res = `perldoc -l DBD::Oracle`;

   $log->log( "Check Install Result: $res" );

   if ( $res )
   {
      $retval = 1;
   }
   else
   {
      $log->log( "==============================" );
      $log->log( "WARNING:" );
      $log->log( "Oracle DBI Components not installed on this host" );
      $log->log( "==============================" );
   }

   return $retval;
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# initialize
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
sub initialize
{
   my $self     = shift;
   my $tns      = shift;
   my $schema   = shift;
   my $password = shift;

   my $method = "initialize";
   $log->log( "*** Enter $method in $self->{classname} ***" );

   $self->set_password( $password );
   $self->set_schema( $schema );
   $self->set_tnsname( $tns );

   $self->log_credentials();

   $self->set_db_handle();

}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# initialize_using_step
# A SQL step should have the tns alias, the schema name and the password set
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
sub initialize_using_step
{
   my $self = shift;
   my $step = shift;

   my $method = "initialize_using_step";
   $log->log( "*** Enter $method in $self->{classname} ***" );

   $self->set_tnsname ( $env->get_tns( $step->{schema}, $step->{database} ) );
   $self->set_schema  ( $step->{schema} );
   $self->set_password( $step->{password} );

   $self->log_credentials();

   if ( ( not $self->{tnsname} ) or ( not $self->{schema} ) or ( not $self->{password} ) )
   {

      $log->log( "========================================" );
      $log->log( "Exception:" );
      $log->log( "Could not get valid database parameters in OracleSqlHelper" );
      $log->log( "One or more of the following values are Null" );
      $log->log( "Database: Schema: Password" );
      $log->log( "========================================" );
      $log->send_err_log();
      die "Will not be able to set the db_handle in OracleSqlHelper";

   }

   $self->set_db_handle();

}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
sub log_credentials
{
   my $self = shift;

   my $tns = $self->{tnsname}   ? $self->{tnsname}  : "<null>";
   my $sch = $self->{schema}    ? $self->{schema}   : "<null>";
   my $pwd = $self->{password}  ? $self->{password} : "<null>";

   $log->log( "SqlHelper Credentials: DB: [$tns] Schema: [$sch]" );
   print "Password: [$pwd]\n";

}


#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# set_db_handle
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
sub set_db_handle
{
   my $self = shift;

   my $method = "set_db_handle";
   $log->log( "*** Enter $method in $self->{classname} ***" );

   $self->{db_handle} = DBI->connect( "dbi:Oracle:$self->{tnsname}", $self->{schema}, $self->{password},
                           { AutoCommit => 0,
                             PrintError => 0,
                             RaiseError => 0,
                             LongReadLen => 20000 }


       ) or do {
               $log->set_logerr( "on" );
               $log->log( "==================================" );
               $log->log( "Exception:" );
               $log->log( "In OracleSqlHelper:set_db_handle" );
               my $estr = DBI->errstr;
               $log->log( "DatbaseError: $estr" );
               $log->log( "==================================" );
               $log->send_err_log();
               die "Can't connect: ". DBI->errstr."\n"; };

               $self->{db_handle}->{RaiseError} = 1;
#   END
#   {
#      $log->log( "END" );
#   }

}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# verify_supplemental_logging
# Parameters: A SQL step.  Contains the parameters tns, schema, password
# Step has the tns alias, the schema and the password
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
sub verify_supplemental_logging
{
   my $self = shift;
   my $step = shift;

   my $retval = 0;

   my $method  = "check_supplemental_logging";
   $log->log( "*** Enter $method in $self->{classname} ***" );

   $self->initialize_using_step( $step );

   my $sqlcmd = "SELECT SUPPLEMENTAL_LOG_DATA_MIN FROM V\$DATABASE";

   $retval = $self->execute_sql( $sqlcmd );

   $self->db_disconnect();

   return $retval;

}


#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# verify_log_mode
# Parameters: A SQL step.  Contains the parameters tns, schema, password
# Returns the query result
# Step has the tns alias, the schema and the password
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
sub verify_log_mode
{
   my $self = shift;
   my $step = shift;

   my $retval = 0;

   my $method  = "check_supplemental_logging";
   $log->log( "*** Enter $method in $self->{classname} ***" );

   $self->initialize_using_step( $step );

   my $sqlcmd = "SELECT LOG_MODE FROM V\$DATABASE";

   $retval = $self->execute_sql( $sqlcmd );

   $self->db_disconnect();

   return $retval;

}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# execute_sql
# Query result MUST be one row only
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
sub execute_sql
{
   my $self = shift;
   my $query = shift;

   my $db_result = "";

   #------------------------------------------------
   # db_handle needs to be set
   #------------------------------------------------
   my $query_handle = $self->{db_handle}->prepare($query);

   $query_handle->execute();
   $query_handle->bind_columns(undef, \$db_result);

   $query_handle->fetch();

   return $db_result;
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
#    $stat = "WC_PVH.get_lates_status( \"ods_bug\" )";
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
sub get_deploy_status
{
   my $self   = shift;
   my $module = shift;

   my $statval;

   eval
   {
      my $func = $self->{db_handle}->prepare( q{
        BEGIN
            :stat := WC_PVH.get_latest_status( p_type => :parameter1 );
        END;
        } );

    $func->bind_param( ":parameter1", $module );
    $func->bind_param_inout( ":stat", \$statval, 50 );
    $func->execute;

   };

    return $statval;
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
#    $stat = "WC_PVH.get_lates_status( \"ods_bug\" )";
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
sub set_deploy_status
{
   my $self   = shift;
   my $module = shift;
   my $value  = shift;

   my $method  = "set_deploy_status";
   my $pmodule = "p_" . $module;

   $log->log( "*** Enter $method in $self->{classname} ***" );
   $log->log( "Will set $pmodule to [$value]" );

   my $func = $self->{db_handle}->prepare( qq(BEGIN WC_PVH.update_version(  $pmodule => ? ); END; ) );

   $func->bind_param( 1, $value );

   if( $@ )
   {
       warn "Execution of stored procedure failed: $DBI::errstr\n";
       $self->{db_handle}->rollback;
   }

   $func->execute;
   $self->{db_handle}->commit;
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# get_latest_version
# Note that the db_handle needs to be set prior to calling this method
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
sub get_latest_version
{
   my $self   = shift;
   my $method = "get_latest_version";

   $log->log( "*** Enter $method in $self->{classname} ***" );

   my $statval;

   if ( not $self->{db_handle} )
   {
      $log->log( "Db_handle not set in $self->{classname}.  Cannot process query" );
      return;
   }

    eval
    {
     my $func = $self->{db_handle}->prepare( q{
        BEGIN
            :stat := WC_PVH.get_latest_version();
        END;
    } );

    $func->bind_param_inout( ":stat", \$statval, 50 );
    $func->execute;

    return $statval;

   };

}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# set_latest_version
# WC_PVH.update_version( p_patch_version => '&1');
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
sub set_latest_version
{
   my $self   = shift;
   my $value  = shift;

   my $method  = "set_latest_version";

   $log->log( "*** Enter $method in $self->{classname} ***" );
   $log->log( "Setting kit version to [$value]" );

   my $func = $self->{db_handle}->prepare( qq(BEGIN WC_PVH.update_version(  p_patch_version => ? ); END; ) );

   $func->bind_param( 1, $value );

   if( $@ )
   {
       warn "Execution of stored procedure failed: $DBI::errstr\n";
       $self->{db_handle}->rollback;
   }

   $func->execute;
   $self->{db_handle}->commit;
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# Connect
# PrintError  => 0,      # Force errors to generate warnings
# RaiseError  => 0,      # Force DBI errors to generate a perl error
# LongReadLen => 20000,  # Max length for LONG and LOB fetches, set to some reasonable value. Default is 80 ;-)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
sub get_multiple_rows
{
   my $self = shift;

   my $VALID_COUNT = 0;

    #------------------------------------------------
    # Make sure the PROJECT_NAME is valid & active
    #------------------------------------------------
    my $query = "select patch_version, patch_date from patch_version_history";

    my $stmt = $self->{db_handle}->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

   # Fetch the data
   while (my ($ver, $pdate) = $stmt->fetchrow_array)
   {
      print "Version: $ver  Dt: $pdate\n";
   }

   $stmt->finish();
}

#-------------

1;
```

Same code worked on a different machine having perl 5.10, *failing on perl 5.16*

I do not know how to check the packages it uses for DBI
I have tried using an older version perl 5.8 on the failed host still same error

*ERROR*

```
2020-07-09 06:41:19 In StatusHelper: Db: [GGATE01_XXXX] Schema: [USERNAME]  Pwd: [*******]
2020-07-09 06:41:19 *** Enter set_db_handle in OracleSqlHelper ***
2020-07-09 06:41:19
Memory fault
```

deploy.pl code

```
# -----------------------------
use Step;
use ConfigFile;
use Date::Manip;
use Spreadsheet::Read;
use Logger;
use StepHelper;
use FileHelper;
use KitHelper;
use Rpd11gHelper;
use DacHelper;
use OdsHelper;
use OdiHelper;
use KMDW_Helper;
use StatusHelper;
use OracleSqlHelper;



# -------------------------------
# Instantiate a StatusHelper
# The StatusHelper can use OracleSqlHelper methods
# It is imperative that the log & env be set as the sqlHelper will use these for instantiation
# Note that if Oracle:DBD components are not installed, the StatusHelper will used std Sql files
# -------------------------------
 
 my $statusHelper = new StatusHelper();

   $statusHelper->set_log( $log );
   $statusHelper->set_env( $env );
   $statusHelper->set_kitHelper( $kitHelper );
   $statusHelper->set_sqlHelper();





elsif ( $install_env eq "ods_host" )
   {
      my $odsHelper = new OdsHelper( $env, $install_env, $ods_param, $phase );

      $odsHelper->set_refresh( $dev_refresh );
      $odsHelper->set_log( $log );
      $odsHelper->set_stepHelper  ( $stepHelper );
      $odsHelper->set_statusHelper( $statusHelper );
      $odsHelper->set_sqlHelper   ();
      $odsHelper->deploy();

   }
```

Comment: How does `deploykit.pl` call `OracleSqlHelper.pm` ? What OS are you using? See also [mcve]

Comment: Operating System: Oracle Linux Server 7.7
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:oracle:linux:7:7:server
            Kernel: Linux 4.1.12-124.34.1.el7uek.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64

Comment: I have added few portions to the original message.. code has a 1000 lines to post it here

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please [edit] your question and bring the code down to a [mcve]? Your `deploy.pl` looks like it won't even compile (`elsif` without `if`). Also, don't use comments to clarify, [edit] the question instead, so that everything is in one place. See also [ask].

Comment: Thanks Robert, That the portion of code i am using..  original code is 1000 lines its too much for the body to accommodate

Comment: Start breaking down your long program so you can remove parts of it to see when you no longer get the error. Whatever part you just removed is the culprit.

Answer (score -1):

It seems, that you forgot a simple "use CGI;"

Without you cant call a new instance!

Good luck...

ps: An answer is much more important than the protocol, which is not recognizable to simple humans. It looks like the midage to me, and will never be the sign of future orientated conversation.